# How to set up SPF records

Tags: c#, .net, spf, braintree

I am working with braintree payment gateway and I want to send emails for receipt and some other notifications to my customers. But I am unable to configure SPF records. I am new in programming field. Can anyone please help me in proper step by step guidance to set up and configure SPF records.

I shall very thankful for your kind help

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Hey Kulbir, I work at Braintree. How you set up SFP providers depends on your DNS provider. If you look at their documentation it should help. If you don't know who that is, then your DNS provider is likely the same as your web host. If you have any Braintree related questions, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).